# Is it possible to have zones inside of zones in Orchard CMS?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, widget, orchardcms

This is my first time using the Orchard CMS for a project and I'm still new to .NET development, so please excuse my lack of knowledge.

I am building a site that will have custom HTML Widgets that will mostly go into the Content Zone. However, I'm also using the Gumby Framework for responsiveness and want to be able to create wrapper DIVs with the Gumby classes that I can put numerous widgets into.

So, for example, there is the Content Zone, which has it's own div. Inside there I'd like to put two other DIVs, one with classes "eight columns" and one with classes "four columns". I'd then like to be able to put my custom widgets into those DIVs.

Is this possible in the Orchard CMS? If so, how would I go about doing this?

Just so you know, I'm using the default TheThemeMachine theme.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, and it is actually the case in the Theme machine: the layout has zones, and each content item gets rendered with local zones, which are what placement targets. For example, on a typical page content item, the Content zone will contain the rendering for the Content shape, which will itself create inner zones, which will receive the shapes for the various parts of the content item, according to what placement.info specifies. In the same way, widgets get rendered as a Content shape, inside of which are local zones, inside of which the shapes for the different parts get rendered.

This is not, however, what you should do. There doesn't seem to be a reason to use zones within zones here. You should just modify your layout.cshtml so that instead of just the one Content zone, you have your wrapper divs, and then two separate zones inside of that.